# Delphi: Deserialize TList<T> using TJson.JsonToObject

Tags: delphi

Consider this test class:

```pascal
TUser = class
  Name: string;
  constructor Create(AName: string);
end;

TTestClass = class
  Users:  TList<TUser>;
  constructor Create;
end;
```

Serialization to JSON works ok, but when I try to deserialize it back, the list is not populated:

```
procedure TForm21.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  u: TUser;
begin
  TestClass := TTestClass.Create;
  TestClass.Users.Add( TUser.Create('Nick'));
  TestClass.Users.Add( TUser.Create('Mike'));

  Memo1.Text := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(TestClass);
  TestClass2 := TJson.JsonToObject<TTestClass>( Memo1.Text );

  for u in TestClass2.Users do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('User %s ', [ u.Name ]));
end;
```

The JSON output is:

```json
{"users":{"listHelper":[2],"items":[["Nick"],["Mike"]]}}
```

Comment: I have confirmed the problem on Delphi 10.1 Berlin, and tested it switching to TJSONMarshal and TJSONUnMarshal with the same negative result.

Comment: Delphi XE5 Users is also empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field names are normally prefixed with "f".
When you rename "users" to "fUsers" your code will work.

Reason is simple when you know it.
The f does not look nice in the json. I guess this is the reason why they remove it, when  present while json is generated and they add it when the json is parsed.

See unit REST.JsonReflect
Method:
TJSONUnMarshal.ConvertFieldNameFromJson
and
TJSONConverter.ConvertFieldNameToJson

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand the answer of "@coding Bott".

If you want to be independent from the "**F**" prefix, you can use the `JSONNameAttribute` which exists at unit `REST.Json.Types`, in order to specify the name of your fields in the class.

Your example can change as:

```
TTestClass = class
  [JSONName('Users')]
  Users:  TList<TUser>;
  constructor Create;
end;
```

As you can see at `TJSONConverter.ConvertFieldNameToJson`, the method first checks if JsonNameAttribute is applied, and if not, the regular rules apply.